# Automatically Delete Columns from CSV?

Tags: macos, csv

In my line of work i deal with a lot of CSV files and every day begins with logging into different networks, generating CSVs for the past day, and analyzing that data.  I'm trying to speed up the process of this and one of the things I'm trying to do is remove data that is not needed from the CSV. As an example, some of the columns I do not need are `date`, `ctr`, and `impressions`. Is there a way to delete these when the csv is downloaded or a way to do it after the file is downloaded?

Comment: There's plenty of ways to modify CSV's. Have you made any attempts to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OSX is based on Unix, I'm pretty sure the `cut` command line utility is preinstalled.

Classic `cut` is one of the most efficient ways of removing columns from a CSV file.